# How to change the tab size in QML TextEdit?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I use a `TextEdit` component for a code editor in my Qt 5.5 application. When pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or pasting snippets from other editors, a default tab size is applied (which is huge) and I just can't find a way to change that value.

My workaround is to forward key events to a C++ controller where I do stuff like inserting `myCustomTabSize` times `spaceCharacter` for each `Qt::Key_Tab` event. Or manually prepare strings from the clipboard before pasting them.

The `QTextEdit` class provides a `setTabStopWidth` method. Is there a QML equivalent for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the tab size in QML TextEdit follow next steps:

1) Set `objectName` to `TextEdit`.

```
TextEdit {
    objectName: "myTextEdit"
}
```

2) Get access to `TextEdit` from c++.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QObject *root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
QObject *textEdit = root->findChild<QObject*>(QStringLiteral("myTextEdit"));
```

3) Get `QTextDocument`, associated with `TextEdit`.

```
QQuickTextDocument *quickTextDocument = textEdit->property("textDocument").value<QQuickTextDocument*>();
QTextDocument *document = quickTextDocument->textDocument();
```

4) Get default `QTextOption`.

```
QTextOption textOptions = document->defaultTextOption();
```

5) Sets the distance in device units between tab stops

```
textOptions.setTabStop(10);
```

6) Set options to document.

```
document->setDefaultTextOption(textOptions);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. However, I would avoid searching in the object tree. I think it's cleaner and more flexible to forward the [TextEdit.textDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) property to a [QQuickTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html) property on the C++ side in order to access the  `QTextDocument`.